# If condition to compare listbox selected value to value in a class

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, listboxitem

I am trying to make an if condition, where the I compare the selected value to a name value I have created in another class.

//I populate the list with the following code:

```
module.Add(new Modules(code, name, semester, preReq, lSlot, tSlot, info));
```

//I populate the listbox with the following code:

```
foreach (object o in module)
        {
            Modules m = (Modules)o;
            selectionBox.Items.Add(m);
            //foreach statement loops for object in module and adds the name to the listbox
        }
```

//The condition is this:

```
if (selectionBox.SelectedItem.Equals(((Modules)selectionBox.Items[i]).mName))
```

So my question would be what if condition would be valid for me to be able to compare the listbox selected value and the index of the module name value?

Comment: And the question / problem is......?

Comment: What if condition would be valid for me to be able to compare the listbox selected value and the index of the module name value.

Comment: I just don't understand you...

Comment: The listbox selected item will be the item that you added (i.e. the Modules object) and you are comparing it to the mName - likely a string... remove the ".mName" from the condition and try again...

Answer (score 1):

Each item in the selectionBox is a Module instance, you can't compare a whole object against a single property of another or same instance of the same class.

Try to divide your test

```
 Modules m = selectionBox.SelectedItem as Modules;
 if(m.nName == (selectionBox.Items[i] as Modules).mName)
     ......
```

of course this is true if you wish to compare the mName property of the selectedItems against a mName property of an arbitrary [i] item in the selectionbox. If you instead want to compare the object instance then the comparison should be

```
 Modules selected = selectionBox.SelectedItem as Modules;
 Modules aModule = selectionBox.Items[i] as Modules;
 if (selected.Equals(aModule))
    .....
```

EDIT: Using a `List<Modules>`

```
List<Modules> modulesList = new List<Modules>();
modulesList.Add(new Modules(code, name, semester, preReq, lSlot, tSlot, info));
.....    
foreach(Modules m in modulesList)
{
     // No cast needed here...
     selectionBox.Items.Add(m);
}
.....
// Find an element....
if(modulesList.Contains(m))
    ....
```

Comment: Sorry I am not sure by 'Module' do you mean the class Module or the list called modules? As right now I have an error

Comment: Answer Fixed ..... (Modules is the right one) However I suggest to differentiate the names to avoid confusion. Just for curiosity, how is defined the variable `module`?

Comment: It is defined as an array list and it appears as though it has worked now just a spelling error when I entered your code.

Comment: Good. but again, if it is possible, use a List(Of Modules), you will have many more functionality with a Generic List